# sort_by with Boolean in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, boolean

I know that boolean in Ruby are classes. But from practical point of view, is there a way to sort an array by boolean (i.e., with all elements with true value first)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You could cheat and get it to return a number:

```
sort_by { |a| a.thing ? 0 : 1 }
```

Comment: To have explicit priorities, could do `m = {true => 0, false => 1, nil => 2}` then `[nil, false, nil, true, nil].sort_by { |a| m[a] }` which would put all the `nil`s last.

Answer (score 21):

You could use partition and then flatten the results:

```
partition{|v| v == true}.flatten
```

Comment: If you want to be on the safe side and avoid any unintended changes, you may want to use `flatten(1)`. However, if you know that the elements can't be flattened, then the above code is fine as it's more concise. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten

Comment: You don't need to do an explicit comparison `v == true` because `v`, in this case, already returns `true`.

Comment: If we want to be more Rubyish and clever, we can call #itself on the objects as we partition them, which is equivalent to the given solution:

    [true, false, true].partition(&:itself).flatten
    #=> [true, true, false]

Answer (score 17):

By using [ActiveRecord's order](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) (included in Rails):

```
collection.order(thing: :desc)
```

Comment: Best answer! Let's do the ordering on SQL side not in the retrieved records.

Comment: I don't think this answer goes well with Ruby booleans, because they cannot be represented with `0` and `1` (we've got `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`). Additionally databases are also tricky, see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19726

Answer (score 5):

Since there are a couple different ways represented here, I went ahead and benchmarked them to see which is fastest, sorting 27,000 items based upon a boolean attribute:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
sort_by     0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.075203)
partition   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.114667)
order       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000046)
------------------------------------ total: 0.180000sec

            user     system      total        real
sort_by     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.016611)
partition   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.111384)
order       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000047)
```

So yes, keeping things on the SQL side definitely makes things faster.