# Sort based on association's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a method in `Business` which is the `certified?` method.

I would like to sort `Quotation` model using the `certified?` method.

The return value of that method is a boolean. So to sort it, I would like to have the certified businesses on top of the list.

Here's the association:

`Business` belongs to `Quotation`

Here's how I do it for now:

`Quotation.by_biz_id(biz.id).includes(:business).sort_by {|quote| quote.business.certified? <=> quote.business.certified? }`

As you can see there are lots of method chaining in it. Is there newer and better way to refactor the code?

Especially the repeating condition: `{|quote| quote.business.certified? <=> quote.business.certified?}`

If I remove the `<=>` condition, the error is something like this:

`ArgumentError: comparison of FalseClass with true failed`

Comment: Is this `certified` a field in your `businesses` table, or a *regular* Ruby method?

Comment: It's just a regular method. And it returns a Boolean value.

Comment: My answer was incorrect. Here is the good example of what you need to do:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737111/sort-by-with-boolean-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `group_by` instead of sorting like,

```
Quotation.includes(:business).group_by do |quote|
  quote.business.certified? ? "certified" : "not_certified"
end
```

It will return `Hash` containing keys as `certified` with values of certified business quotation and remaining in `not_certified`.